# What is the best way to call a function from action form in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit, database-connection

I want to insert data in a MySQL database with PHP and XHTML.

I have my functions of database in a single file: `database.inc.php`, in this file I wrote a lot of functions: `function insert_city($_POST)`, `function insert_state($_POST)`, `function insert_customer($_POST)`, etc.

I'd like know the best way to call these functions. For each transaction I have a `XHTML` file.

For example. This is the structure of my `addcustomer` form:

```
<form action="addcustomer.php" method="POST">
  <input>...
  </input>
</form>
```

From this file I am calling to another `PHP` file called `addcustomer.php`. This file has more or less the following content:

```
<?php
include('database.inc.php');
if (insert_state($_POST)){
  echo "Good";
} else {
  echo "Bad insertion";
}
?>
```

With this approach I am losing my forms, after the user inserts its data I'd like to show the form and the error message or success.

I know is a good practice group the functions into one file, but I don't like to write scripts like the one above, I'd prefer write each function in different file.

Tips, advices or reprimands?

Answer (score 1):

Set the action of the form to `""` or `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` so that when the form is submitted the same file is loaded.

Then at the top of that file you add something like:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post' ) {
    require( 'addcustomer.php' );
    if (insert_state($_POST)){
        $form_status = "Good";
    } else {
        $form_status =  "Bad insertion";
    }
}
```

Then you can use $form_status to display a message in your form.

Ideally though you want to separate the code from the html, but that a different lesson.

Comment: I think it's fine to lose that separation (slightly) when it comes to small websites and one or two forms on the entire site. Though you should know if your website grows large, you should consider MVC, or even a framework.

Comment: I agree, but its not complicated to put the code in one file and view in another.

Comment: @Galen where I can a good article about "that different lesson"?

Comment: read everything you can about the MVC pattern. Basically, you keep the logic separate from the presentation (or php code separate from the html code).